# finding the consecutive 1's til the count of 6

Tags: python-3.x

```
t = int(input(""))

for _ in range(t):

    lst = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))

    for i in range (len(lst)):

        if(lst[i]==1 and lst[i+1]==1):

            print("no")

        else:

            print("yes")
```

Here i'm trying to check whether consecutive ones are present or not but my if statement is not working

Comment: change `for i in range (len(lst)):` to`for i in range (len(lst)-1):` to avoid IndexError when doing `if(lst[i]==1 and lst[i+1]==1):` on the last letter

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Add the stacktrace and error description to your question

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for that.

```
import re
i = 'aaasdsdaa11111111as1dasdb1asdasda11bbasdasdb'
print(re.findall('[1]{2,}',i))
```

this regex prints all occurences that have 2 or more consecutives 1's.

You can use this one if you want 2-6 consecutives 1's.

```
import re
i = 'aaasdsdaa11111111111111111111111111111111as1dasdb1asdasda11bbasdasdb'
print(re.findall('[1]{2,6}',i))
```

hope it helps.